# How to change UIWebView font for text/plain data

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is it possible to change the font used when loading text/plain data, using loadData, in to UIWebView?  It uses some mono-space font that my boss isn't happy with.

Before you mark as duplicate, please notice I'm asking about text/plain data, not text/html content-type.

Due to other parts of my design it isn't easy for me to just use a UITextView or other control.

If your answer is "convert text to HTML", please keep in mind that there are a lot of issues converting text to HTML, so unless iOS gives me a simple way to do that and handle all of the issues, I don't see that as a robust solution.  The text comes from a huge database of all kinds of text that various users have entered, so I'd have to handle every possible string/text.